# how to get the status of the last command along with its output in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, spark-submit

i am trying to get the status of the last command also i want the output to be stored in logfile.

```
{spark_home}/bin/spark-submit .....> 2>&1 | tee -a log1.txt
if [$? -eq 0] ; then
echo " success"
else
echo "fail"
applicationId= $(grep command to get the app id from log1.txt)
```

but as $? is checking for last status command , its always showing as 0 ie successful as i am writing the output  to logfile. can someone help me how to get the status as well as write logs of the spark-submit to log file

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1):

When you use pipe with bash, you could read all command statue in `PIPESTATUS` array:

```bash
$ ls | grep spamandegg
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 1
```

Here `ls` is Ok but `grep` token is not found.

The length of the array is equal to the number of commands in pipe sequence.

For you, the exit status of your spark-submit command is in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`

Comment: sorry, if u understood my question... I am executing spark-submit, i want the status of Spark -submit to check in if loop  .. also i want its output to be stored in logfile at the same time...